# Balls in Bins simulation for R

Tags: r, probability, poisson

I would like to simulate the distribution for a fixed number of balls `m` in a fixed number of bins `n` in R. Up till now I have been using the Poisson approximation with `rpois()`. This is a decent approximation for a large number of balls in `n` bins.

However, `rpois()` only allows you to indicate a rate `lambda`, which is `m/n`. As a consequence, the number of positive bins is often smaller than the number of balls.

Would anybody know of a function or script that allows me to randomly distribute balls into bins?

Ultimately I seek to calculate the confidence intervals of `-log(empty bins/total bins)` by bootstrapping. 
This problem is 'breaking my balls' so to speak.

Comment: Great set up. Didn't see it coming.

Comment: `sample(n, m, replace = TRUE)`?

Comment: `rmultinom(x, m, rep(1,n))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want the multinomial distribution.

Here's a quick function - we take m balls in n bins, and give x results, returning a vector of your metric for each of the x trials:

```
myfunc <- function(m,n,x){
  out <- rmultinom(x,m,rep(1,n))
  -log(colSums(out == 0)/n)
}

myfunc(10,40,10)
[1] 0.1923719 0.2548922 0.2231436 0.2548922 0.2876821 0.2876821 0.2231436 0.2231436 0.2231436 0.2548922
```

You can then get the quantiles/Confidence intervals:

```
out = myfunc(10,40,1000)
quantile(out, c(0.05,0.95))
       5%       95% 
0.1923719 0.2876821
```

Comment: Folks, thanks a lot for your help, this has both answered my question and massively sped up my bootstrapping. Still fairly new to R myself, but getting more familiar one step at a time. I'll put up some finished code when ready.